# Blocking eChecks in PayPal

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I'm currently testing Express Checkout, Payflow Advanced (hosted pages) and Payflow Pro (transparent redirect).  I'm looking for a way to block eChecks.

The obvious solution would be to go into my PayPal account to Profile > My Selling Tools > Block payments. Click checkbox for Block the following payments: Pay with eCheck or German bank transfer for all website payments except eBay.  But that has no effect in any of the 3 scenarios!  Is that because I'm in test mode?  Will this work in Live mode?

Otherwise I've got to do it in code.

In Express Checkout - using NVP you can use

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly
```

In Express checkout SDK you can use

```
paymentDetails.AllowedPaymentMethod = AllowedPaymentMethodType.INSTANTPAYMENTONLY;
```

In Express Checkout for Payflow (Payflow pro) I tried the following but it does not work

```
ECSetRequest setRequest = new ECSetRequest(...);
setRequest.PaymentType = "instantonly";
```

And for Payflow Advanced, when I create the token I used the following NVP which also did not work

```
PAYMENTTYPE=instantonly
```

So I'm 1 for 3 on coding.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, this is probably because you are in test mode and using the sandbox

Comment: I'll report back on test results when I go to live mode

Answer (score 0):

Strange,

```
    ECSetRequest setRequest = new ECSetRequest(...);
    setRequest.PaymentType = "InstantOnly";
```

Should work according to the `ECSetRequest.GenerateRequest();` ..

```
    this.RequestBuffer.Append(PayflowUtility.AppendToRequest("PAYMENTTYPE", this.mPaymentType));
```

However, I cannot find anything in any of the Payflow documents to suggest that you can pass `PAYMENTTYPE`, it seems so only be in the responses.

My testing has resulted in not being able to get `PAYMENTTYPE` to work with Payflow at all.

This will only work when using the MerchantSDK or talking directly to the Merchant NVP servers.

Comment: If you want this feature added to Payflow my best suggestion is to submit a feature request on [PayPal's Developer Technical Support Site](http://paypal.com/dts)